# finite field and relationship between subfield and subgroup

Tags: finite-fields

Please help or hints me to solve this question:

Prove: if $F$ is a finite field, then $H \cup \{0\}$ is a subfield of $F$ for every subgroup $H$ of the multiplicative group $F^*$ if and only if the order of $F^*$ is either $1$ or a prime number of the form $2^p - 1$ with a prime $p$.

Comment: $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$ is a field with $p^n$ elements and $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}^*$ is a cyclic group with $p^n-1$ elements. What are the subgroups of $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}^*$, the subfields of $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$, what if $n$ is prime, and if $p^n-1$ is prime ?

Comment: @ reuns, The order of subgroup $F^*_{p^n}$ is divided by $p^n-1$, The order of subfield $H$ of $F^*_{p^n}$ is $p^s$ where $s|n$.

Comment: You mean $N | p^n-1$  and $p^s$ and $s | n$. What if $n$ is prime, what if $p^n-1$ is prime ?

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, Thanks.

Comment: @ reuns, I can not prove that $p=2$ in $p^n -1$. Please help me.

Comment: $p$ is prime. What happens if it is odd ? What are the subgroups of $\mathbf{F}_5^*$ ?

Comment: Because $F^*$ is cyclic, what must happen is that all the divisors of $p^n-1$ must be of the form $p^m-1$ where $m\mid n$. That is a tall order in most cases.

Comment: The answer can be found in the following question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980751/finite-field-where-each-subgroup-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-nonzero-elements